# C# Have user input string to a key DES

Tags: c#, encryption, key, des

In my C# program I am encrypting/decrypting files. I copied this code from the Microsoft website to toy with it and dissect it. I'm asking if any of you know how I would have a pre-determined string act as the key for the encryption/decryption.

In my main method:

```
string sSecretKey;
sSecretKey = GenerateKey();
```

GenerateKey:

```
static string GenerateKey()
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider desCrypto = 
                 (DESCryptoServiceProvider) DESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
    return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desCrypto.Key);
}
```

This is in my encrypt and decrypt function: I have no idea what they do

```
DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of depends on what you want to do. In the following line...

```
ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desCrypto.Key);
```

You are fetching an ascii representation of an automatically generated key for the encryption object. The property `DES.Key` though, has both a public `set` and a public `get`, so you can do:

```
// Set key to a pre-determined set of bytes (of length 8):
desCrypto.Key = new byte[] {0x4b, 0x4a, 0x41, 0x52, 0x54, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x21};
```

Ofcourse the value of this, when the next line decodes `desCrypto.Key` into a string, the bytes will be "decoded" from hex into [more readable ascii characters](http://www.asciitable.com/) (assuming you've provided some meaningful hex values to begin with, ofcourse).